# Is it possible to use query key parameter as variable?

Tags: supertest

Normally one can query in the following way:

```
  .query({
      key1: value1,
      ...
      keyN: valueN
    })
```

But can I use instead of "hard" key values variables?

like following:

```
.query({
      varKey1: value1,
      ...
      varKeyN: valueN
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Assuming varKey1, ... varKeyN are some variables:

```
.query({
  [varKey1]: value1,
  ...
  [varKeyN]: valueN
 })
```